# MySQL configuration, allow truncate to execute when reference table is empty

Tags: mysql, truncate

I have the exact same code running on two different servers:

```
Truncate table2;
Truncate table1;
```

Both table structures are exactly the same in both servers, table2 has a foreign key referencing table1.

Since table2 was truncated before table1, it is empty and there are no keys pointing to table1, so truncating table2 shouldn't be a problem. **But!!!:**

In one server it works perfectly well and on the other I get a foreign key constraint error:

```
Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint (user`.`table2`, 
CONSTRAINT `table2_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ID`) REFERENCES `user`.`table1` (`ID`))
```

I can understand from this that there must be a setting that can be changed in order to always allow to truncate empty tables. If not server one should give me the same error.

I know I can use delete instead but it is a longer process and auto_increment needs to be reset in that case.

**I just want to understand why server 1 has no error and server 2 does.**

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Just drop the index, truncate the table, and add the foreign key again.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; TRUNCATE table1; SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Comment: Good, but I don't have to run that query on server 1, it just allows me to do it, I guess there is some mysql configuration to be done.

Comment: It must be set to 0 on server 1 already. For data integrity, it is best to keep it to 1. That is why I set it back to 1 in the query.

Comment: No :( that is not the case, it is set to ON (1) on both servers.